# Run Lauterbach t32tcpusb from a docker container: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lauterbach

I am relatively new to docker.
I want to setup a server that can serve multiple Lauterbach Debuggers using t32tcpusb.
But unfortunately, if I serve them all with a single instance, then only one user can connect to one of the Lauterbachs.

As t32tcpusb does not support multiple instances, I want to containerize it.

- Pull-in only one USB device
- Provide one tcp-port for that device

(Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Lauterbach is installed to ~/t32)

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    t32:
        image: alpine
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb 

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32" #Pull-in the software
          - "/dev/bus/usb/003/005:/dev/bus/usb/003/005" #Pull-in only one of the devices
          #- "/dev/usb:/dev/usb" #For testing: Pull-in all devs

        expose:
          - 8455
        ports:
          - "8455:8455"
```

Running it like that results in

```
fileuser@fileserver:~/docker_test$ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating docker_test_t32_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_test_t32_1
t32_1  | exec /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb: no such file or directory
```

(If I just prpend `ls` to the command, it shows that the path itself is valid)
Is there anything obviously wrong with my compose file?
Is it feasible to just use a minimal image and pull-in the executables I need?

Comment: What you're describing isn't usually a best practice; it's usually better to build a reproducible image that contains the software directly in the image.  Trying to use unmodified base images and especially Alpine can run into trouble if the image doesn't contain C shared libraries that you need, and this does usually result in a `no such file or directory` error.

Comment: Hi David, as I only got an executable setup file that installs itself, I thought I try it that way. But at least I just found a solution, will post it separately.

Comment: You can `RUN` it in your Dockerfile, then.  (Assuming the right C shared libraries exist; you may need to `apk add` or `apt-get install` them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled into a solution for my specific issue.
Using `image: ubuntu` instead of `alpine` works better, especially, if the software provided is compiled to run on ubuntu :)

Then the SW will find all the libraries it will need.